# What is most common name of pants used for exercise?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Among 'athletic pants', 'sport pants', 'workout pants', which is the most common name used in AmE?

Comment: Probably "sweats".

Comment: I'm not sure if people still wear 'sweats' or 'sweat pants', @StoneyB. The word *sweat* is so unsanitary.

Comment: @pazzo Well, the only Millennial I know is my son, and he uses it. Granted, he grew up with me; but, countervailingly, he's a musician.

Comment: @pazzo My high school students call most workout pants *sweats* or *sweat pants* still.  *Yoga pants* are common as well.

Comment: Gym pants?  @Jason et al.

Comment: In Br.E. I say "tracksuit bottoms" or "trackie b's" more colloquially. (I appreciate the question was about AmE, but for comparison's sake...)

Comment: @JMB I was giggling to myself about the Br.E. point of view of my answer the entire time I wrote it.  There's a lot of pants...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of words used for this type of clothing.

**Athletic pants** would be understood, but it sounds more like the type of term used by clothing manufacturers to describe this category of clothing.  You wouldn't normally hear two people at a gym describing their pants to one another with this phrase.

**Workout pants** would be usable for any sort of pants of this type.  People are more specific about what they are wearing usually, but if you said something like:

> Give me a minute to change into my workout pants before we leave for the gym.

it would be perfectly normal.  Workout pants can also refer to a variety of uncategorized pants or be used for pants whose category is unknown.

Loose fitting cotton or polyester pants like the ones shown below are commonly called *sweat pants* (or sometimes sweatpants.)
[image: gray sweats]
Source:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweatpants#/media/File:Sweatpants.jpg

If the pants are lightweight and nylon, they are often called *warm up pants*, and can be part of a *tracksuit*.  If they have snaps down the sides they are *tear away pants*.  Both varieties are sometimes called *basketball pants*.  The woman below is wearing a tracksuit, a matching pair of warmup pants and jacket.

[image: blue tracksuit]

 Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracksuit#/media/File:FashionTracksuit.jpg

Finally, there are form fitting pants that have become popular with women in the US in the past few years that are called *yoga pants*.  They are very similar to sweat pants, but are usually much tighter fitting.  Be aware that searching for images of yoga pants will probably not be safe for work.

[image: Rated G yoga pants]
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoga_pants#/media/File:Wrap_Pant_1.jpg

All images were cropped and resized.

Comment: And *leotards*? And I still say gym pants and bicycle pants, and I say stretch pants, not yoga pants. There's quite a variety...

Comment: @pazzo Good points all.  Women's clothing in particular seems to be subdivided into a huge number of categories.  In my mind, *leotards* are generally worn for dancing or gymnastics these days.

Comment: In my mind is Elaine Benes... wearing her leotard and tights at the gym. Or Michelle Pfeiffer in a (*uses Dr Evil voice*) catsuit.